# How to solve this:Struct In Collection not changed

Tags: c#, .net, list, struct

I have a problem working with structs.

I have this struct:

```
struct MyStruct
{
  public int x;
  public int y;

  public MyStruct(int x,int y)
  {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }
}
```

When i try to add this struct to a list like this:

```
List<MyStruct> myList = new List<MyStruct>();

// Create a few instances of struct and add to list
myList.Add(new MyStruct(1, 2));
myList.Add(new MyStruct(3, 4));
myList[1].x = 1;//<=====Compile-time error!
```

I get this error:

```
Compile-time error: Can't modify '...' because it's not a variable
```

Why am I getting this error and how to solve it?

Comment: Why are you using a `struct`?

Comment: It seems to me this question is already covered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1067340/c-sharp-modifying-structs-in-a-listt

Answer (score 4):

**A struct is normally mutable, i.e. you can modify the values of its members directly.**

According to this [website](http://csharp.2000things.com/2013/02/12/778-a-struct-isnt-mutable-when-used-in-a-collection/):

However, if a struct is used in a collection class, like a List, you can’t modify its members.  Referencing the item by indexing into the collection returns a copy of the struct, which you can’t modify.  To change an item in the list, you need to create a new instance of the struct.

```
    List<MyStruct> myList = new List<MyStruct>();

 // Create a few instances of struct and add to list
myList.Add(new MyStruct(1, 2));
myList.Add(new MyStruct(3, 4));
myList[1].x = 1;//<=====Compile-time error!

 // Do this instead
 myList[1] = new MyStruct(1,myList[1].y);
```

If you store the structs in an array, then you can change the value of one of the struct’s members.

```
 MyStruct[] arr = new MyStruct[2];
 arr[0] = new MyStruct(1, 1);
 arr[0].x= 5.0;  // OK
```

Comment: You *can* modify the copy (if you store it in a variable), but it's the *copy* that gets modified, not the original struct in the List.